# iReport make multiple reports in one resultset

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using a query in jrxml and it has resultset like below:

**name**  -   **description**  -   **value**

xyz -----  desc1    -------       2
xyz -----     desc2 -------          55
xyz -----     desc3       -------    54
pqr   -----   desc1      -------     6
pqr  -----    desc2    -------       44
pqr   -----   desc3    -------       77

the name goes in header part and rest of the data goes in table part.
i want new page of report for each different name. How to do in iReport 3.7.5?

Comment: implemented it by grouping the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create group for the `name` field and set **`isStartNewPage`** property for the `Group` band.

The sample:

```xml
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT name, description, value FROM table_name ORDER BY name]]>
</queryString>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<group name="nameGroup" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Name: " + $F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```